# How do I get total in a foreach loop

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have a div that displays items , quantities and total prices for each item using a foreach loop. I now want to get the total amount and dont seem to get it.
This is my blade file

```
<div class="order-summary">
   <div class="order-col">
      <div><strong>PRODUCT</strong></div>
      <div><strong>TOTAL</strong></div>
   </div>
   <div class="order-products">
      @if(session('cart'))
      @foreach(session('cart') as $id => $details)
      <?php
         $total = 0;
         $total += $details['price'] * $details['quantity'] ;
         $total_amount += $details['price'] * $details['quantity'];

         ?>
      <div class="order-col">
         <div>
            <h4 class="nomargin">{{$details['quantity'] }}x {{ $details['name'] }}</h4>
         </div>
         <div>KSh {{ $total }}</div>
      </div>
      @endforeach
      @endif
   </div>
   <hr>
   <div class="order-col">
      <div>Shiping</div>
      <div><strong>KSh 300</strong></div>
   </div>
   <hr>
   <div class="order-col">
      <div><strong>TOTAL</strong></div>
      <?php $total_amount += $total?>
      <div><strong class="order-total">KSh {{ $total_amount }} </strong></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I have also tried `<div><strong class="order-total">KSh <?php echo $total_amount?> </strong></div>` but still does not work.

I get an error of undefined variable total_amount. How do I go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables `$total` and `$total_amount` must be outside of the foreach
here I have rewritten your code

```
<div class="order-summary">
    <div class="order-col">
        <div><strong>PRODUCT</strong></div>
        <div><strong>TOTAL</strong></div>
    </div>

    @php $total = 0; $total_amount = 0; @endphp

    <div class="order-products">

        @if(session('cart'))
        @foreach(session('cart') as $id => $details)

        @php
        $total += $details['price'] * $details['quantity'] ;
        $total_amount += $details['price'] * $details['quantity'];
        @endphp

        <div class="order-col">
            <div>
                <h4 class="nomargin">{{$details['quantity'] }}x {{ $details['name'] }}</h4>
            </div>
            <div>KSh {{ $total }}</div>
        </div>

        @endforeach
        @endif

    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="order-col">
        <div>Shiping</div>
        <div><strong>KSh 300</strong></div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="order-col">
        <div><strong>TOTAL</strong></div>

        @php $total_amount += $total; @endphp

        <div><strong class="order-total">KSh {{ $total_amount }} </strong></div>
    </div>
</div>
```